# Need SQL Query for accessing different serial numbers present in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table containing "ID" column. 
Different numeric ids are present in this column from 1000 to 9999.
(1000, 1001.....,5000,5001....,8000,8001....,9000....9999).
Now I need a "**generic**" query which will give me distinct starting id series number present in this column.
for example, desired output

```
1000,
5000,
8000,
9000
```

If in future 7000 series is added in the ID column then output of the same query should include 7000 also in list like

```
1000,5000,7000,8000,9000
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: No not like this. Generic for data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT min(id) from tablename group by SUBSTRING(id, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it if your series start with every thousand

```sql
SELECT id
  FROM table1
 WHERE id % 1000 = 0
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ae01/2)** demo

---

Now here is a generic way which treats every "island" in id values (a sequence of values where next = prev + 1) as a series. This way a series can start and stop with any value

```
SELECT t1.id
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id + 1
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0693/2)** demo

Comment: Thanks peterm. It even better   :)

Answer (score 1):

try this and its for 2 zeros..

```
select * from table where id like '%000' or id like '%00';
```

Comment: I would have thought that an ID Column was not a String

Comment: @user2310289 i tried it and its worked

Comment: @user2310289: the solution is relying on implicit data type conversion and the fact that SQL Server and MySQL (the two DBMS tagged in the question) are pretty forgiving when it comes to datatype checking. The query would fail on DBMS with a more strict data type check (e.g. Postgres).

Comment: Ah, I am a postgres guy.  Good to know it works.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail, if a new series starts with say 7500?

Comment: @Raj i feel you need only 000 after number as above you mention thats y i give this answer..i try to figure out it

Comment: @Raj: it would not fail for `7500`. But `75000` would (incorrectly) be returned. Peterm's answer is the correct one (and it's much more "generic")

Comment: @Raj i am edited answer...now its depends your condition...its 2 zero or 3zero or etc...

Comment: Thanks Anshul Parashar. It has solved my problem. I couldn't imagine it would be so simple.